# Meaning of the category of sets

Tags: category-theory, terminology

There are several set theories, is there a category of sets for each of them? For example, ZF-Set, ZFC-Set, NBG-Set, etc…

Comment: Do you also ask if there are several universes of sets, one for each set theory? The category of sets is exactly as well defined as the universe of sets. If that is not well defined for you, then the category of sets is also not well defined.

Comment: @ZhenLin I did not know about the universe, but I just looked up the Grothendieck universe. Is a category of all sets based on an axiomatic set theory + existence axiom of (Grothendieck) universe? Are there several universes for each set theory?

Comment: @ZhenLin I disagree with this, and think these two situations are not analogous. Set theory is almost always introduced to people via "here are the constructions you can do with sets", whereas the category of sets is rarely introduced that way. If it was, this question wouldn't exist: e.g. if they introduce the construction *whenever you have an epimorphism, you can take its section*, it would conclusively rule out what Hayatsu refers to as ZF-Set.

Comment: @Hayatsu I am not talking about Grothendieck universes. I am talking about the universe of all sets, traditionally denoted $V$.

Comment: @Z.A.K. The category of sets is defined in terms of the universe of sets. If the universe of sets does not satisfy the axiom of choice then the same is true of the category of sets. I do not refer to ETCS or other direct axiomatisations of the category of sets.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When your definition of a category starts like this

> A category consists of a set $C_0$ of objects and for each $x,y\in C_0$ a set $C_1(x,y)$ together with...

and your meta-theory is one of the standard set theories like ZFC, then you will not be able to form a category $Set$ of all sets. This is because famously there can be no set $Set_0$ of all sets. There are several work-arounds.

- You can conservatively extend your meta-set-theory (for example ZFC) to one which can speak about classes and sets (for example NBG). You can then change your definition to "A category consists of a class $C_0$ of objects together with...". Since there is a class of all sets, you are able to form $Set$.
- You can form the small category $Set_\kappa$ of sets which are smaller than a certain cardinal number. The underlying set of that category can not consist of all sets whose cardinality is less than $\kappa$, since this is still a proper class, but it can be for example the set of all cardinals which are less than $\kappa$. The properties of the category $Set_\kappa$ dependend on the closure properties of $\kappa$ and the axioms of your meta-theory. For example when your meta-theory has choice, then all epimorphisms will be split in $Set_\kappa$. If you like to have a category $Set_\kappa$ which behaves as if it were the category of sets of ZFC, then you can add an extra axiom, namely the existence of Grothendieck universes, and let $\kappa$ be such a universe.

But if you want to study directly how the properties of a set theory influence the properties of "its category of sets", then you can also follow the following approach. You study the various material set theories (first-order single sorted theories whith a single relation symbol $\in$) and their models. You need a meta-theory for that, but this can be anything (although it need be sufficiently strong so that you can show the existence of some models). Then you can associate to a model $(V,\in)$ of say ZF a category $Set_{(V,\in)}$ of sets whose underlying set of objects is the underlying set $V$ of the model. The properties which all the categories $Set_{(V,\in)}$ share, where $(V,\in)$ ranges over the models of a particular set theory, will depend on the set theory in question.

The most detailed paper which compares material and structural set theories and the properties of their associated categories is the paper *Stack Semantics* by Mike Shulman. It is a tough read though.